# App crashing whenever button clicked?

Tags: android

Having an issue with an app I've started building. Whenever I press the button on screen, the whole thing crashes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because the code is pretty much identical to another app I was testing out the same features on, and works fine there. 
Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationReceivedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Participant;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMessage;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMessageReceivedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomConfig;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomStatusUpdateListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomUpdateListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, RoomUpdateListener, RealTimeMessageReceivedListener, RoomStatusUpdateListener {

public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
final static int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;
final static int RC_WAITING_ROOM = 10002;
boolean mPlaying = false;
private String mRoomId;
private Room mRoom;
private OnInvitationReceivedListener mListener;
private String TAG = "Chip In";
private int MIN_PLAYERS = 2;

public void onStartMatchClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

}

// returns whether there are enough players to start the game - in this case 2
boolean shouldStartGame(Room room) {
    int connectedPlayers = 0;
    for (Participant p : room.getParticipants()) {
        if (p.isConnectedToRoom()) ++connectedPlayers;
    }
    return connectedPlayers >= MIN_PLAYERS;
}

// Returns whether the room is in a state where the game should be cancelled.
boolean shouldCancelGame(Room room) {
    mRoomId = room.getRoomId();
    mRoom = room;
    // TODO: Your game-specific cancellation logic here. For example, you might decide to
    // cancel the game if enough people have declined the invitation or left the room.
    // You can check a participant's status with Participant.getStatus().
    // (Also, your UI should have a Cancel button that cancels the game too)
    return false;
}

public void testMethod(View view) {
    Intent quickGameIntent = new Intent(this, Help.class);
    startActivity(quickGameIntent);
}

public void quickGame() {

    // auto-matches specified range of players
    Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);

    // Room configuration
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();

    // Create RTM room
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);

    // Screen stays on during handshake!
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // go to game screen
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
        if (response == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // get the invitee list
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                    data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

            // get auto-match criteria
            Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
            int minAutoMatchPlayers =
                    data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
            int maxAutoMatchPlayers =
                    data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);

            if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
                autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                        minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
            } else {
                autoMatchCriteria = null;
            }

            // create the room and specify a variant if appropriate
            RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
            roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
            if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
                roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
            }
            RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);

            // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
        else if (response == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Waiting room was dismissed with the back button. The meaning of this
            // action is up to the game. You may choose to leave the room and cancel the
            // match, or do something else like minimize the waiting room and
            // continue to connect in the background.

            // in this example, we take the simple approach and just leave the room:
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
        else if (response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
            // player wants to leave the room.
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
}

// create a RoomConfigBuilder that's appropriate for your implementation
private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    return RoomConfig.builder(this).setMessageReceivedListener(this).setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    if (connectionHint != null) {
        Invitation inv = connectionHint.getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);

        if (inv != null) {
            // accept invitation
            RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
            roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(inv.getInvitationId());
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfigBuilder.build());

            // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            // go to game screen
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

// RoomUpdateListener methods:
// this three methods overridden
@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        // let screen go to sleep
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // show error message, return to main screen.

        return;
    }
    // get waiting room intent
    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}

@Override
public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) {
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        // let screen go to sleep
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // show error message, return to main screen.

        return;
    }
    // get waiting room intent
    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}

@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) {
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        // let screen go to sleep
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // show error message, return to main screen.
    }
}

// Players Connected overridden methods
@Override
public void onPeersConnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    if (mPlaying) {
        // add new player to an ongoing game
    } else if (shouldStartGame(room)) {
        // start game!
    }
}

@Override
public void onPeersDisconnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    if (mPlaying) {
        // do game-specific handling of this -- remove player's avatar
        // from the screen, etc. If not enough players are left for
        // the game to go on, end the game and leave the room.
    } else if (shouldCancelGame(room)) {
        // cancel the game
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPeerLeft(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    // peer left -- see if game should be canceled
    if (!mPlaying && shouldCancelGame(room)) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPeerDeclined(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    // peer declined invitation -- see if game should be canceled
    if (!mPlaying && shouldCancelGame(room)) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}

// code from: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/83dda7c60e13b6c129a8e104437ec69d8a257fa0/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity.java
@Override
public void onLeftRoom(int statusCode, String roomId) {
    // we have left the room; return to main screen.
    Log.d(TAG, "onLeftRoom, code " + statusCode);
    switchToMainScreen();
}

private void switchToMainScreen() {
}

// RealTimeMessage methods
@Override
public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage realTimeMessage) {

}

// RoomStatusUpdateListenerMethods
@Override
public void onRoomConnecting(Room room) {

}

@Override
public void onRoomAutoMatching(Room room) {

}

@Override
public void onPeerInvitedToRoom(Room room, List<String> list) {

}



@Override
public void onPeerJoined(Room room, List<String> list) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectedToRoom(Room room) {

}

// overridden code
@Override
public void onDisconnectedFromRoom(Room room) {
    // leave the room
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);

    // clear the flag that keeps the screen on
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // show error message and return to main screen
}

@Override
public void onP2PConnected(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onP2PDisconnected(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

}
```

Errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.anna.chipin, PID: 8039
              Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.avn.quadralumino, iconPack:com.avn.quadralumino, fontPkg:com.avn.quadralumino, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.avn.quadralumino, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.avn.quadralumino}
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.games.Games.zzi(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.RealTimeMultiplayerImpl.getSelectOpponentsIntent(Unknown Source)
                  at com.example.anna.chipin.Menu.onStartMatchClicked(Menu.java:44)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.anna.chipin.Menu">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="signOut"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Help"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button5" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Main Menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Quick Game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onStartMatchClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Scoreboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Custom Game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post also `activity_main.xml`

Comment: I think you are setting click listener in the xml file and the method name is not matching what you have assigned in the xml with the one in  the java file. But as @azizbekian said without xml file there is no way to know.

Comment: The error is not that `OnClick` method is not working.
The error that `GoogleApiClient` is required in the `Help` Activity

Comment: I connect google api in the previous activity, must it be connected each time?

Comment: Yes. It's a brand new instance of the variable. If you don't use the other, or pass that one to this activity (if you even can), then it's null, and you'll get exceptions

Comment: @Nah., in xml you have line `android:onClick="signOut"`. Where is method `signOut()` in the hosting activity?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you never initialize your `GoogleApiClient` (`mGoogleApiClient` is never initialize, and you pass a null value to intent).

Please refer to the [manual](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), and disable the button until the api client in connected.